# Why do I keep getting lnK2019 error In clion using QT

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a qt project in Clion but every time I try to run it it gives me this error it says there is a unresolved external in function WinMain but it doesn't exist
"
[1/1] Linking CXX executable untitled.exe
FAILED: untitled.exe
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2022.2.4\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\untitled.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100220~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1434~1.319\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\untitled.dir\untitled_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp.obj  /out:untitled.exe /implib:untitled.lib /pdb:untitled.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:windows  -DYNAMICBASE -NXCOMPAT -LARGEADDRESSAWARE  C:\Qt\6.4.1\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt6Widgetsd.lib  C:\Qt\6.4.1\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt6Guid.lib  C:\Qt\6.4.1\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt6Cored.lib  mpr.lib  userenv.lib  C:\Qt\6.4.1\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt6EntryPointd.lib  shell32.lib  d3d11.lib  dxgi.lib  dxguid.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1434~1.319\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\untitled.dir\untitled_autogen\mocs_compilation.cpp.obj /out:untitled.exe /implib:untitled.lib /pdb:untitled.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:windows -DYNAMICBASE -NXCOMPAT -LARGEADDRESSAWARE C:\Qt\6.4.1\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt6Widgetsd.lib C:\Qt\6.4.1\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt6Guid.lib C:\Qt\6.4.1\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt6Cored.lib mpr.lib userenv.lib C:\Qt\6.4.1\msvc2019_64\lib\Qt6EntryPointd.lib shell32.lib d3d11.lib dxgi.lib dxguid.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\untitled.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\untitled.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
Qt6EntryPointd.lib(qtentrypoint_win.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function WinMain
untitled.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed."
"

here is my cmake file as well
"

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)


if (WIN32)
    project(untitled LANGUAGES CXX)
elseif(UNIX)
    project(untitled)
endif()

set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Release;RelWithDebInfo" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

#======================= INCLUSION OF Qt =======================#
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/dev/vcpkg/ports")
find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED
        COMPONENTS Core Widgets Gui
        )

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
#=================== INCLUSION OF Project Files ====================#
set(FORMS_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/forms")
set(INCLUDE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
set(SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

include_directories(${FORMS_DIR})
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${SOURCE_DIR})

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
        "${FORMS_DIR}/*.ui"
        "${FORMS_DIR}/*.qrc"
        "${INCLUDE_DIR}/*.h"
        "${SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp"
        )

#=================== SETUP EXECTUABLE ====================#
# Enable debug logging on RELWITHDEBINFO configuration
set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS
        $<$<CONFIG:RELWITHDEBINFO>:QT_MESSAGELOGCONTEXT>
        )

# Add the forms directory to the AUTOUIC search paths
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS ${CMAKE_AUTOUIC_SEARCH_PATHS} ${FORMS_DIR})

# Add the executable
if (WIN32)
    qt_add_executable(untitled WIN32 ${SOURCES})

elseif(UNIX)
    qt_add_executable(untitled ${SOURCES})
endif()

# Add the target includes for MY_PROJECT
target_include_directories(untitled PRIVATE ${FORMS_DIR})
target_include_directories(untitled PRIVATE ${INCLUDE_DIR})
target_include_directories(untitled PRIVATE ${SOURCE_DIR})

#===================== LINKING LIBRARIES =======================#
target_link_libraries(untitled PRIVATE Qt6::Widgets Qt6::Core Qt6::Gui)
"

I tried searching other posts and qt website but found nothing I looked up the error but was unable to find where this function "WinMain" came from
```

Comment: The error message is saying that you have not defined a `main` function. Have you?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to change this qt_add_executable(untitled WIN32 ${SOURCES}) to qt_add_executable(untitled main.cpp)